# PHP Find String inside Text

Tags: php, regex, string, find

What is the best/easiest way to find a string (with PHP) inside a text with:

- Any kind of special characters
- String boundary (space)
- Case insensitive

Some examples:

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?"; 
$find = "èsàDò";
```

Will return `true`

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?"; 
$find = "a TEST èsàdò";
```

Will return `true`

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "string123";
```

Will return `true`

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "string12";
```

Will return `false`

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "This is a test èsàdò String123?";
```

Will return `true`

Comment: The main problem is to clearly define what is a boundary. Once done, it's easy.

Comment: Double posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: @DanielElmnas almost. the accepted answer does not take word boundaries into account.

Comment: No, since `string123` returns true in your 3rd example.

Comment: Right, well it seems to be working with stripos! Sorry for double post!

Comment: No, it doesn't (and can't), see the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't define what you call a "boundary", I assumed (from your tests) it means that the searched substring can be surrounded with spaces, punctuation characters and limits of the string. To express that I used negative lookarounds:

- `(?<![^\s\pP])` *(not preceded with a character that isn't a space or a punctuation character)*
- `(?![^\s\pP])` *(not followed with a character that isn't a space or a punctuation character)*

Note that I used negative lookarounds (instead of `(?<=[\s\pP])` and `(?=[\s\pP])`) to implicitly include cases where the searched string begins or ends at one of the limits of the string. In other words:

- `(?<![^\s\pP])` <=> `(?<=[\s\pP]|^)`
- `(?![^\s\pP])` <=> `(?=[\s\pP]|$)`

Code:

```
$text = 'This is a test èsàdò string123?'; 
$needles = ['èsàDò', 'a TEST èsàdò', 'string123', 'string12', 'This is a test èsàdò String123?'];

$format = " %-35s\t%s%s";
echo 'TEST STRING: ', $text, PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
printf($format, 'needle', 'result', PHP_EOL);
echo str_repeat('-', 50), PHP_EOL;

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    $pattern = '~(?<![^\s\pP])' . preg_quote($needle, '~') . '(?![^\s\pP])~iu';
    printf($format, $needle, (preg_match($pattern, $text) ? 'true' : 'false'), PHP_EOL);
}
```

Result:

```
TEST STRING: This is a test èsàdò string123?

 needle                                 result
--------------------------------------------------
 èsàDò                                  true
 a TEST èsàdò                           true
 string123                              true
 string12                               false
 This is a test èsàdò String123?        true
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode at your 'boundary'/delimiter, then loop over the array and return on the first match.

```
$array = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($array as $array_item){
    if (stripos($array_item, 'èsàdò') !== false) {
        return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: `$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "string12";` will return `true` in your case But it's not expected in Question

Comment: I didn't realise that was a requirement to find whole words. In that case, preg_match with a regex is fine, as has just been posted.

Comment: My answer was able to do same in efficient manner but due to that I have removed mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex functions like preg_match or preg_match_all

Example :

Sample : 
EDIT : (Thanks to Thomas Ghesquière who found a working pattern just below)

```
function test($string,$pattern){
   return (preg_match("/\b({$pattern})\b/ui","".trim($string)."",$res)) ? "Found" : "Not found";

}



$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?"; 
$find = "èsàDò"; 
echo test($text,$find) . "\n";


$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?"; 
$find = "a TEST èsàdò";
echo test($text,$find) . "\n";


$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "string123";
echo test($text,$find) . "\n";


$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "string12";
echo test($text,$find) . "\n";


$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "This is a test èsàdò String123?";
echo test($text,$find) . "\n";
```

will return true of false, depending on $text and $find.  Here it will return true. 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php

sizrar@ovador:~$ php test.php

Found

Found

Found

Not found

Found

You can see the results are nearly OK (still some tuning for your last example but th main principle is there) 
In this special case you could easily rule out the equality case in the testing function. But to determine what regular expression to use , you can use en online tester like : https://regex101.com/ and complète the first argument of preg_match accordingly

Comment: You have forgotten the third example (that doesn't work with your pattern).

Comment: Hmm, you're rigjt, I'm editing it. (pasted the wrong buffer ... )

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\b` word delimiter for your regular expressions and `u` for matching accented characters.

```
$text = "This is a test èsàdò string123?";
$find = "èsàDò";
// remove trailing punctuations from $find
// punctuations inside the string are not affected
$find = preg_replace('/([[:punct:]]+)$/iu', '', $find);
// escape any regex specific character
$find = preg_quote($find);

if (preg_match("/\b({$find})\b/ui", $text)) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the last test that ends with a literal `?` (no word boundary here)

Comment: Now that you mention it, since I just updated the answer to make sure that specific regular expression characters are escaped from the input string, that last one is a no-go.

Comment: Updated to remove the punctuations from the search string, so the last query will find a match, even though it's ending punctuations may differ.

Answer (score -1):

To match any of the following:

- Any kind of special characters
- String boundary (space)
- Case insensitive

i would look into preg_match [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

using a regex you can then search for any string that matches special characters or string boudaries and if it is set with the i flag it will be case insensitive.

for example: 
`preg_match("/([èsàDò\b]+)/i"'This is a test èsàdò string123?',$matches)`
this will retrieve any matches into the $matches array, or for just a boolean true/false:

```
if(preg_match("/[èsàDò\b]+/i"'This is a test èsàdò string123?')){
[CODE HERE]
}
```